# Insert in sequelize.query and then return the inserted row

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Is there a way of returning the inserted row by a raw insert query in sequelize?

The `returning` option doesn't change anything im the returned value. Is returning the counting of inserted rows and a empty array instead of the inserted rows: `[ [], 1 ]`

```js
let contato = await sequelize.query(
    'INSERT INTO public.contato(nome, telefone, id_empresa, id_status) VALUES ($nome, $telefone, $id_empresa, $id_status);',
    {
        bind: {
            nome: form.nome,
            telefone: form.telefone,
            id_empresa: filaChat.id_empresa,
            id_status: 1,
        },
        type: QueryTypes.INSERT,
        returning: true,
    }
);
```

Comment: What do you have set for the dialect on the connection?

Comment: `dialect: 'postgres'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For postgress, you need `RETURNING id` included in the raw query.

```
INSERT INTO public.contato(nome, telefone, id_empresa, id_status)
VALUES ($nome, $telefone, $id_empresa, $id_status)
RETURNING id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your late answer. it worked like a charm, saved me from doing the other query to get the id. The `returning: true` is useless in this case.

Comment: We can get all the keys with `RETURNING *`